# Cutting scene results in choppy transition

Tags: video, video-editor, editing, transitions

I used the Razor tool in Openshot to remove a scene from a movie. However, the transition between the two surrounding scenes is now very choppy. The movie is now simply two separate clips. Is there a way to "fuse" the two clips together, so the transition is smooth?

Answer (score 1):

The two most common approaches, if you don't have [B-roll](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-roll) coverage, is either a dissolve (usually a cross-dissolve) or a fade-out/fade-in (usually dip-to-black).  Garish effects (essentially all the others offered in a typical NLE) can also be used (but are usually avoided).

IF the clip you are cutting out means joining what looks like a single take (with a discontinuity in the middle), the dip is your friend.  If the clip you are cutting out takes you from one scene to another, the cross dissolve can also work.  A series of cross-dissolves can work to show the passage of time (where the camera stays fixed and the subject is seen doing on thing, fading into doing another, etc.).

Comment: can these functions be found on openshot?

Comment: Yes, openshot does have transitions, and they have both dissolves and fades.  They also have a plethora of garish effects if you really want to call attention to the transition instead of letting the story and the video imagery speak for itself.